# How to mix outputcache with BeItMemcached? (or other cache provider)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-2.0, memcached, outputcache

I want to change the data source of the outputcache of asp .net, how can I do that?
I work with .net 2.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to implement a `caching provider` which uses `BeltMemcached` and register this provider with via `<system.web>`.

`BeltMemcached` comes with the methods `Add` / `Get` / `Set` / `Delete` which can be mapped to the needed methods `Add` / `Get` / `Set` / `Remove` of your custom provider...

Relevant links including code for a sample provider:

- https://web.archive.org/web/20211020121627/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/061610-1.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.outputcacheprovider.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.outputcache.aspx
- http://code.google.com/p/beitmemcached/
- http://galratner.com/blogs/net/archive/2010/06/06/write-your-own-outputcacheprovider.aspx

**EDIT :**

**AFTER** my answer the OP added the requirement for ASP.NET 2.0 .
The above is only valid for ASP.NET 4 and up... hence in ASP.NET 2.0 custom caching providers are not supported...

Comment: .NET supports what you ask for starting with ASP.NET 4.0... this is NOT possible with ASP.NET 2.0 - IF you must do this with ASP.NET 2.0 THEN you have to implement your own caching infrastructure from scratch... can't recommend that though...